# How do I evaluate this limit :$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty} (1+\cos x)^\frac{1}{\cos x}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I would like to know if this :$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} (1+\cos x)^\frac{1}{\cos x}$$ does exist and how do i evaluate it ?.

**Note** : I have tried to use the standard limit : $$ \lim_{z\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)^z=e$$ using $\cos x=1/z $ but i can't 
succeed

Thank you for any help .

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that $\cos$ is periodic to show that $(1 + \cos(x))^{\sec(x)}$ is periodic as well. Then, if a function $f(x)$ is periodic, does $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exist?

Comment: Also using your note, $z\to\infty$ means $x\to 0$, so that approach would not work.

Comment: this is the problem in this limit

Comment: I said also it is not work , only i see may there is a relationship bewteen 2

Comment: @user3002473 Constant functions are periodic but their limit as $x\to\infty$ exists. One must also show that the function is not constant.

Comment: @Guest That's an important distinction to make, thank you! It's pretty easy to see $f(x) = (1 + \cos{x})^{\sec{x}}$ isn't constant, since $f(0) = 2$ and $f(\pi/4) = (1 + 1/\sqrt{2})^\sqrt{2} \ne 2$.

Comment: The function whose limit you're taking depends on $x$ only through $\cos x$, and $\cos x$ oscillates as $x\to\infty$, so your function also oscillates, albeit in a more complicated way. So it doesn't have a limit. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any natural number $n$, if $x=2n\pi$ ,the value  of the function is 2; if $x=(2n+1/2)\pi$, the value is 1. So no convergence.

Comment: sorry to tel you that x go to infty

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Substitute $x = 2n\pi$ and let $n$ go to $\infty$. Then $x \to \infty$ as well.

Comment: This is clever, so you can argue that such limits of periodic functions don't exist because they are not unique. +1